# How to convert Spark text table to csv

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some tables which might be generated from the Spark database and has already been saved as plain txt.

I would like to convert them to csv but have few ideas.

I understand python if needed.

```
Total battles: 49173
 Avg. weight/team: 0.024
 + ---- + ------------------ + --------- + ------ + ------- + ------ + ------- + 
 | Rank | Pokemon            | Usage %   | Raw    | %       | Real   | %       | 
 + ---- + ------------------ + --------- + ------ + ------- + ------ + ------- + 
 | 1    | Latios             | 47.02101% | 27308  | 27.767% | 19934  | 26.329% | 
 | 2    | Ferrothorn         | 37.38366% | 28015  | 28.486% | 24272  | 32.058% | 
 | 3    | Tyranitar          | 36.37828% | 19087  | 19.408% | 15814  | 20.887% | 
 | 4    | Landorus-Therian   | 30.18429% | 14058  | 14.294% | 11847  | 15.647% | 
 | 5    | Politoed           | 28.25530% | 21053  | 21.407% | 18584  | 24.545% | 
 | 6    | Garchomp           | 27.02130% | 21281  | 21.639% | 16577  | 21.895% |
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

`pd.read_csv('untitled.txt', skiprows=3, sep='|').iloc[1:,:-1]`